# How to invert colors of content of part of a page behind div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to invert all colours behind the div with class invert in css (preferably) or in javascript?
The `filter: invert(100%)` seems to only affect the content within the div.

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 min-height:100%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.invert {
 filter: invert(100%);
 -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left: 50%;
 z-index:0;
}

.feed {
    margin:0px;
 padding: 25px;
 color:white;
 background:black;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: right;
 width: 50%;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left: 25%;
 z-index:-1;
}
.black {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background:black
}
h1 {
 font-size:26px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Void Site</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="feed">
<h1>Feed</h1>
</div>
<div class="invert"><div class="black"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the invert class on your body and that should get the desired effect.

Comment: Sorry about wrong title, I have corrected it. That would invert entire page, I want only the part behind the div

Comment: That would be rendering your page to canvas and then inverting a quadrant of that. There isn't a way to overlay an inversion filter via CSS.

Comment: This shows you how to render DOM to canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas